Ladders or scaffolding to reach this soffit
I need to work on the soffit underneath the second floor roof. Below the second floor roof is a first floor roof which prevents me from leaning a ladder from the ground. (see picture). What kind of scaffolding, ladders, or equipment could I use to safely reach the soffit? I don't want to spend a ton of money, but I do want to be safe.


I see four roofs and four soffits, please clarify exactly which ones you're trying to work on.

It looks like a good job for a rental man lift.

Two roof jacks (that match your roof's pitch) with a 6x6 on them, then one end of a plank on that and the other on an extension ladder, to get to the lower section. To get the top, just put the plank on the peak and on a ladder jack on an extension ladder - half hanging off that corner of the house that has one less foot of roof sticking out....

Can you reach the soffit in question standing on the 1st floor (porch?) roof?

I'm talking about standing on the roof with the solar panels and trying to reach the second floor soffit next to it. It is a good 8 ft from the roof to the soffit so I cannot reach it.

For jobs like these, I usually use a lightweight ladder placed on top of the lower roof. But more important than the method of getting up there, is the method of preventing a fall. Whatever you do, get a harness, lanyard, and a rope safely tied. Sooner or later, you'll run out of luck. Last time I fell, it was less than 10', but still enough to break several bones. Oh, and they had to glue back one of my ears back in place.
